# Could not find Windows Runtime type in docker

Tags: c#, docker, uwp, .net-core, dockerfile

I have created one .Net Core Console App for reading BLE messages and i have referenced Widows.winmd for using BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher (Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement.BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher). i have run "dotnet publish -c Realease -r win10-x86" and docker build from publish folder image created successfully but i am getting error while running container. How can i fix that??

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
ENTRYPOINT ConsoleApp1.exe
```

**Docker build result:**

```
PS C:\Temp\UwpClassLibrary\ConsoleApp1\bin\Realease\netcoreapp2.0\win10-x86\publish> docker build -t consoleble .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 60.74MB
Step 1/4 : FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
---> db8182d67b6c
Step 2/4 : WORKDIR /app
---> Using cache
---> 72ad458b28d3
Step 3/4 : COPY . ./
---> d87225a29b50
Step 4/4 : ENTRYPOINT ConsoleApp1.exe
---> Running in a96daa3f030f
Removing intermediate container a96daa3f030f
---> a6f3d8500e20
Successfully built a6f3d8500e20
Successfully tagged consoleble:latest
```

**Error:**

```
PS C:\Temp\UwpClassLibrary\ConsoleApp1\bin\Realease\netcoreapp2.0\win10-x86\publish> docker run consoleble

Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not find Windows Runtime type 'Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement.BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher'.
at ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

**.csproj File**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Windows">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\Windows.winmd</HintPath>
      <IsWinMDFile>true</IsWinMDFile>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Is that capability actually supported in Server Core? Looking at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt844528(v=vs.85).aspx a lot of bluetooth functionality is missing but I don't know enough to make a call either way.

Comment: Yes, you are right but i need to work with that, question is how can i make it possible ?

Comment: According to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/bluetooth/general-bluetooth-support-in-windows "Windows Server 2016 does not support bluetooth" so there's not likely to be an easy answer - what's the context for needing to be able to do (something like) this?